# the number of inform moderator flags remaining can not be read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: screenshot drawing attention to the problem]

The black number partly within, partly without a dark red circle is illegible to me.

Comment: i'm looking into this now

Comment: Cool. No rush. I don't plan to use my quota!

Answer (score 1):

A part of this is fixed, the rest will be after the next build of the site.

Comment: In light of [this request](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/1501/5472) - should this question still be marked status-completed?